# PHP Notice: Undefined index al generar reporte con PHPExcel

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estoy generando un reporte en Excel sin embargo cuando trato de sumar dos columnas y mostrarlas en: sumaHoras= fechaEntrada + fechaSalida

a) El resultado es exitoso siempre y cuando la operación la realice de esta forma:

```
->setCellValue('I'. $i, abs($datos['fechaEntrada']- $datos['fechaSalida']));
//celda I sera el resultado de sumaHoras
    foreach ($empleados as $row) {

    $datos = $db-> consultarFecha($row['idemp'],$row['fecha']);

    $suma = ($datos['fechaEntrada']- $datos['fechaSalida']);


    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A' .$i, $row['idemp'])
            ->setCellValue('B'. $i, $row['Nombre'])
            ->setCellValue('C'. $i, $row['fecha'])
            ->setCellValue('D'. $i, $row['horas'])
            ->setCellValue('E'. $i, $row['area'])
            ->setCellValue('F'. $i, $detalles['depto'])
            ->setCellValue('G'. $i, $datos['fechaEntrada'])
            ->setCellValue('H'. $i, $datos['fechaSalida'])
            ->setCellValue('I'. $i, abs($datos['fechaEntrada']- $datos['fechaSalida']));
            //->setCellValue('I'. $i, $datos['sumaHoras']);

    $i++;
}
```

1) El resultado sera el esperado siempre y cuando (fechaEntrada sea en AM) +(fechaSalida sea en PM)

[image: Caso a]

2) El resultado sera exitoso **no importando que** fechaEntrada y fechaSalida no contengan datos.

Sin embargo para la opción a) no suma correctamente los campos fechaEntrada en PM + fechaSalida en AM.

[image: Suma HorasPM + HorasAM]

b) El resultado es exitoso siempre y cuando la operación la realice de esta forma y cumpa con los números a continuación:

```
->setCellValue('I'. $i, $datos['sumaHoras']);

    foreach ($empleados as $row) {

    $datos = $db-> consultarFecha($row['idemp'],$row['fecha']);

    $suma = ($datos['fechaEntrada']- $datos['fechaSalida']);


    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A' .$i, $row['idemp'])
            ->setCellValue('B'. $i, $row['Nombre'])
            ->setCellValue('C'. $i, $row['fecha'])
            ->setCellValue('D'. $i, $row['horas'])
            ->setCellValue('E'. $i, $row['area'])
            ->setCellValue('F'. $i, $detalles['depto'])
            ->setCellValue('G'. $i, $datos['fechaEntrada'])
            ->setCellValue('H'. $i, $datos['fechaSalida'])
            //->setCellValue('I'. $i, abs($datos['fechaEntrada']- $datos['fechaSalida']));
            ->setCellValue('I'. $i, $datos['sumaHoras']);


    $i++;
}
```

1) El resultado sera exitoso siempre que fechaEntrada y fechaSalida contengan datos.

```
Entrada      Salida    Horas

/22:22:46   06:10:51    8/
/22:09:00   06:03:00    8/
/21:32:02   06:05:36    9/
/21:30:03   06:12:35    9/
/21:30:03   06:12:35    9/
```

2) Resultado exitoso si campo fechaEntrada o fechaSalida son fechas anteriores a la actual.

> Ejemplo FechaActual 27/06/2017, fechaEntrada y fechaSalida < a fechaActual

3) Si fechaEntrada o fechaSalida no contienen datos o fechaEntrada y fechaSalida son posteriores a la actual (los reportes siempre van a manejar una fecha posterior a la actual) el reporte no se genera y muestra el siguiente error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index:> sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235
>
> PHP Notice: Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235

"Por lo que note es que el numero de lineas de error(`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:\..\..\..\excelrpt.php on line 235`)  es igual al numero de registros que no contienen una fechaEntrada o fechaSalida"

Consulta a la BDD ->`DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras` --> Hace posible la suma de formato PM a AM

```
public function consultarFecha($empno,$fechainicio)
{
$res = Array("idclave"=>"","fechaEntrada"=>"","fechaSalida"=>"");

$qry = "select
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada, 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras 
         from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 
           fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 00:00:00', 103) and 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,$qry);

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() . " qry " .$qry, true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $res["fechaEntrada"] = $row['fechaEntrada'];
    $res["fechaSalida"] = $row['fechaSalida'];
    $res["sumaHoras"] = $row['sumaHoras'];

}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

return  $res;
}
```

## Intentos

1)-Intente desde la consulta poner una fecha por default, la fechaEntrada e incluso la fechaSalida si se setearon a `'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'` sin embargo el resultado fue el mismo:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235

```
$qry = "select
            CASE WHEN fechaEntrada IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), fechaEntrada, 108) END AS 
            [fechaEntrada],
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida, 
            DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras 
           from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 
            fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 
             00:00:00', 103) and 
            CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";
```

2-Intente validar desde PHPexcel:

```
setCellValue('I',$i,'=IF(sumaHoras==15,6,fechaEntrada+fechaSalida)');
```

3- Intente partir de esta operación:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime($datos['fechaEntrada']);
$datetime2 = strtotime($datos['fechaSalida']);
$interval  = abs($datetime1 - $datetime2);
$horas   = round(($interval / 60)/60);
```

y asignarla a:

```
->setCellValue('I'. $i, $horas);
```

En resumen la opcion B es la correcta pero no logro corregir cuando se cumplen las condiciones del inciso b) y sale el error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sumaHoras in A:......\excelrpt.php on line 235

Que es cuando 1 o muchos registros tienen fechas posteriores a la actual es decir esas fechas aun no se cumplen, pero cuando se cumplan evidentemente el reporte se generara ya que las fechasEntrada y fechaSalida serán < a la fechaActual; sin embargo los reportes deben generarse no importando que esos campos no contengan datos así como en la opción a).

Comment: El error indica que en el array en el que recibes tus datos no hay ninguna clave que se llame `sumaHoras`. Podrás verificar lo que hay dentro del array haciendo esto por ejemplo. `print_r($datos);`  Imprimiendo el contenido del array que intentas leer y que da problemas. Es posible que: 1. `sumaHoras` no exista del todo, o que exista, pero en un nivel más interior del array, o sea, dentro de otra clave del array. El error es claro, **no encuentra ninguna clave en el array que se llame `sumaHoras`**.

Comment: Segun la implementación hecha sumHoras viene apartir de un Alias hecha en la consulta  DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras  y posteriormente en:  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $res["fechaEntrada"] = $row['fechaEntrada'];
    $res["fechaSalida"] = $row['fechaSalida'];
    $res["sumaHoras"] = $row['sumaHoras'];

}

Comment: Sí. Pero no des por seguro que esa consulta está funcionando y que te está devolviendo lo que esperas. Almacena el resultado de la consulta y verifícalo con `print_r($resultado);`. Como te decía , el mensaje de error es muy claro: en las claves del array no hay ninguna que se llame `sumHoras`